# ClickOnce error after deploying -- has a different computed hash than specified in manifest

Tags: deployment, clickonce, vsto

Afer deploying my VSTO add-in with ClickOnce, I get the following error message when trying to launch setup.exe:

> File, Addin.resources.dll, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.

Why is this happening? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to resolve this just by doing a clean build and publish. For some reason the manifest wasn't updated like it was supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is super old, but putting it here for anyone who comes by in search of an answer.

It is described on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd465291(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN. I'm adding the main commands here in case the page disappears.

You can add a few commands on your build server to resign the manifest. After publishing, execute each command inside the folder containing the manifest and the vsto, respectively.

```
mage -sign ExcelWorkbook.dll.manifest -certfile ExcelWorkbook_TemporaryKey.pfx

mage -update ExcelWorkbook.vsto -appmanifest "Application Files\Ex
celWorkbook_1_0_0_0\ExcelWorkbook.dll.manifest" -certfile "Application Files\ExcelWorkbook_1_0_0_0\ExcelWorkbook_TemporaryKey.pfx"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 SP2, and am having the same issue.

Regularly, I will create a new release of our Excel Addin by Rebuilding the solution in VS, signing it, deploying it, but it is uninstallable.

[image: ComputedHash]

If I then quit Visual Studio, then run Visual Studio again, Rebuild and Redeploy, then it'll work without any problems.  Which is fine... but, of course, it means each time I deploy, I need to check that the damn thing will install okay !

It's worrying that VS continues to build installables which quietly contain this issue.

There are plenty of articles mentioning this bug, errr, issue (some from 8 years ago !!), suggesting I need to "rebuild my manifest file", but why doesn't this happen automatically when a do Rebuild in Visual Studio..?

[ClickOnce Deployment Issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/92ef0ad2-532a-41f1-ae11-3addbe9f0434/clickonce-deployment-issue-file-has-different-computed-hash-than-specified-in-manifest-urgent?forum=winformssetup)

[ClickOnce Deployment Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231063/clickonce-deployment-error-different-computed-hash-than-specified-in-manifest)

Answer (score 0):

It is super simple, just go to your Project directory and delete bin and obj directories, after that compile your application again.

For me it was the solution.