# ClickOnce Deployment Error: different computed hash than specified in manifest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

I keep on running across this error when trying to deploy via ClickOnce

```
File, image.jpg, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.
```

I realize that this is an error that has a lot of google results but I have been unable to resolve this. The stranger part is that this ClickOnce package has been deployed on a variety of other machines (at least 30) without any issues - this is only happening on one specific machine with Windows 7 and x64.

On the one hand, I have checked the manifest file and the version numbers don't match as they should and I've heard that this can be the cause of the error. This doesnt make sense because I checked the server the files are on and everything matches there.

On other hand, I know this package works on other machines and this is the first machine coming up with this error.

Finally, I've also tried all the "usual" fixes for this. I have signed the package, I have erased all files from the deployment server, I have cleaned, rebuilt and redeployed the application and none of these work.

Help!

Comment: If anyone lands on this thread, I came across the same error. For me it was Git changing LF with CRLF, hence changing the content of the file post hash creation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to regenerate the application manifest. This happens when you change file contents and do not update your manifests accordingly.

[Mage.exe MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't explain why sometimes doing a Clean\Rebuild\Publish fixes the issue, and sometimes it doesn't.   My biggest problem is that VS doesn't warn me that it's just created a "bad" Excel Addin VSTO file... so after publishing and deploying my Addins, I have to manually install them on my machine to check if they will actually ever work or not.

Comment: It should not be a requirement for people to fiddle with manifest files when VS is quite capable of generating a working ClickOnce deployment, when the planets are in alignment anyway. ;)  [Tell me more](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34718733/585968)

Answer (score 3):

We were deploying to 2 servers using the same URL, with the routers load-balancing between them. Deploying to the 2 servers resulted in differences between the manifest files on each server, and the error. What worked was to deploy to only one server, and then copy the application folder to the other server.

Answer (score -3):

You need to delete all the files from your debug folder and need to regenerate the application manifest. This happens when you change file contents and do not update your manifests accordingly.

Comment: You appear to be **plagiarizing** [BentOnCoding's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6231271/585968) with regard to _"This happens when you change file contents and do not update your manifests accordingly."_