# What steps do you need to take to regenerate the manifest when using Click Once deployment

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce

There are a number of questions stating you have to regerenate the Manifest of an application when using ClickOnce deployment particularly if you encounter problems.

However I am unclear from articles such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6231271/427684) as to what steps I need to take in order to regenerate my Manifest in Visual Studio 2008? (I understand that I may have to use a third party tool and not Visual Studio to do this?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using Visual Studio to publish? If so, that should update your manifest files.

You can also use Mage. I would start with the [UI version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhctdw55.aspx) and then move to the [command line version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx) once you determine if Mage will work for you. Just opening and saving the manifests should work. When/If you move to the command line version, check out the `-update` command.

Comment: Yep Visual Studio will update the manifest file when it deploys with the one belonging to the most current version of the app.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback guys, I did try those steps and it didn't solve a problem I was having but that is a separate issue. With regards to Visual Studio doing the biz, if you refer to [the SO question I referenced](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6231271/427684), it discusses this needing to be done if you have trouble actually deploying (installing on the users machine) which suggests after Visual Studio is done with it.

Comment: Are you incrementing the version number before you publish with VS?

Comment: @whatknott Yes I am, does that make a difference?

Comment: The version number needs incremented if you want to push a new version. But if you're already doing that it must be something else.