# ClickOnce Deployment error : application validation didnot succeed

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, deployment, clickonce

I have a winforms app deploying with ClickOnce.

But when i try to publish, this generates the error like *application validation did not succeed, please contact application vendor.*

Below given is the error in detail.

*Application manifest has either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash specified at all. 
File, Netspective Fluent XA.exe.manifest, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.*

I tried googling and several options stated, none of them helped, could anyone point out what will be exact issue.

I created a key and signed the manifest. But it still shows error.

Please guide me through!!!!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ClickOnce Deployment Error: different computed hash than specified in manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231063/clickonce-deployment-error-different-computed-hash-than-specified-in-manifest)

Comment: @Herdo : i have tried this already. I created a project from scratch and tried the same, but failed. Also, tried to regenerate manifest. could you please explain the steps to do? I am running .Net 4.0. will that be an issue?

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess what's wrong:

Be sure that "Publishing Folder Location" or "Installation Folder" is the same as user see it. ClickOnce application can be launched only from one of these 2 locations. The problem you described can happen if you manually copied the files to different folder / server.

Comment: I publish to a local folder, and later using git, pushes to the installing location, a webserver location. this is already worked before. Now recently this is raising issue.

Comment: OK. So I assume your "Installation Folder" is different, it points to target location and it is correctly set. Check please these 2 things: 1. Did you update "*.application" file in the target server, too? 2. Ensure that git synchronized really all files correctly (compare your local directory with server content)

Comment: help please, have same problem... where issue ?

Comment: 1. Open <your_app_name>.application file in deployment folder and verify that deploymentProvider represents real path accessible to end users. If not, you must change installation path in your application settings. 2. Publish again and replace server <your_app_name>.application with fresh version.