# Application manifest has either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash specified at all

Tags: c#, clickonce

Hi I am trying to generate click once application setup.

But I am facing the issue as

Application manifest has either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash specified at all

I tried to select certificate from select from store but still it is throwing an exception.

Exception is as below

> Following errors were detected during this operation.     * [8/31/2017
>   11:23:39 AM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException
>   (HashValidation)
>         - Application manifest has either a different computed hash than the one specified or no hash specified at all. 
>         - Source: System.Deployment
>         - Stack trace:          at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest
>   deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri,
>   IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri&
>   appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)            at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId,
>   TempDirectory& downloadTemp)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState&
>   subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)          at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)             at
>   System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri
>   activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String
>   deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings,
>   String& errorPageUrl)

Could you please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: When / where exactly does the error appear and where / how is it reported? Did you check that your certificate is not expired?

Comment: While installing the application I am getting this error. Showing as application validation did not succeed and if I check error log I am getting above error.

Comment: Did you already try to re-create your manifest file? Seems like some tool combinations sometimes don't auto-update the manifest (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231063/clickonce-deployment-error-different-computed-hash-than-specified-in-manifest, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gauravb/2008/10/06/clickonce-filename-has-a-different-computed-hash-than-specified-in-manifest/). You should try some of the linked hints, I'm not an expert for this kind of problem, so I don't know if it will solve your issue.

Comment: Yes I tried to update manifest files but it was not successful.