ClickOnce application compiled with VS 2019 generates an error "File, MyApplication.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest"
I have an old windows application that is deployed usign ClickOnce. When this application project and whole solution containing it is compiled with VS2010 and VS2012 the deployment works well, but if the same solution is compiled using VS2017 or VS2019 the deployment fails on error "File, MyApplication.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest".
I don't know how to proceed to solve this problem. So far I haven't found similar issues from the internet.
My solution contains several projects. Two main projects are the application itself MyApplication.csproj and deployment project MyApplication_deploy.csproj that is of type class library. The MyApplication_deploy project contains only an empty class just for msbuild. This deployment project is compiled as the last project and it contains some post-build events. After successful build it runs
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe "$(ProjectDir)..\MyApplication\MyApplication.csproj"  /p:Configuration=Release /t:Publish /property:PublishDir=$(ProjectDir)..\..\export\MyApplication\;MyAppFolderName=ApplicationFiles

which to my understanding creates a new publish of MyApplication. The other commands in the post-build events are various copy commands that copy some resources to the export folder.
The application files from this export folder are copied under a web site on an installation server from which this application is deployed to clients using ClickOnce. After this application is downloaded from a web site and started this error

Activation of http://installation_server/MySite/MyApplication/ resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
+ File, MyApplication.exe, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.

This happens only if I have compiled this solution with VS2019 or VS2017, now when compiled with VS2010 or VS2012. I have not done any changes to any project or solution files in between.
What could be the reason and also solution for this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1312911/clickonce-error-after-deploying-has-a-different-computed-hash-than-specified?rq=3

Is there any update? Can you provide a minimal example without personal privacy?

@MinxinYu-MSFT, probably I could. What that example should contain?

@HansPassant, I tried resigning the published application. mage -Sign ....\export\MyApplication\ApplicationFiles\MyApplication.exe.manifest -CertFile MyApplicationKey.pfx. That worked well, but updating said "Unrecognized file type - MyApplication.exe". The command I tried was mage -update ....\export\MyApplication\ApplicationFiles\MyApplication.exe -appmanifest "....\export\MyApplication\ApplicationFiles\MyApplication.exe.manifest" -certfile MyApplicationKey.pfx

See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.  Try starting with a new project and copying the minimal code and csproj files to reproduce the problem. Then update the question.

Unfortunately there is no update so far. I haven't had time to prepare a better example. I'm waiting for a solution from another source.

I asked for support from Microsoft to solve this case. They suggested this article https://danielvaughan.org/posts/uwp/2015/08/28/Automaticly-Incrementing-the-Package.appxmanifest-Version-Number/ which actually helped me to solve my problem.
The actions are quite straightforward. A pre-build event action was used to run a powershell script that increments the version number of app.manifest file automatically. The contents of the needed powershell script is included in the linked article.
This Powershell script reads the app.appmanifest file for the project, replaces the Version attribute, and overwrites the app.appmanifest file; leaving the application ready to submit without having to modify the manifest file manually.
This script is executed from my click-once application project's pre-build events. The executed command is
Powershell -File "$(ProjectDir)IncrementVersion.ps1" "$(ProjectDir)\"

After these tricks the deployment of my application was successful.
